# an object with the same key already exists in the object statemanager When trying to add the fallowing data Using EF

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the Relational Database as shown below on the EDM. When I am trying to submit a new F_Orden with two existing F_Producto_ProductoCompra and which has an exisitng FDistributor I get the Error mention on the title. What is the right way to do this? Please any help would really appreciated.

[image: EDM]

```
 using (var context = new DryTypeEntities())
        {
             //**************************************
            //Insert Order              
            FDistributor distributor1 = context.FDistributors.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Dverdesoto");
            F_Producto_ProductoCompra productocompra1 = new F_Producto_ProductoCompra
            {
                FechaExpiracon = "3/13/2015",
                CostoCompra = "1",
                DescuentoCompra = "10%",
                Id = 2
            };

            F_Producto_ProductoCompra productocompra2 = new F_Producto_ProductoCompra
            {
                FechaExpiracon = "3/13/2015",
                CostoCompra = "1",
                DescuentoCompra = "10%",
                Id = 3
            };

            F_Orden orden1 = new F_Orden
            {
                Fecha = DateTime.Now,
                Total = 12,
            };

            orden1.F_Producto_ProductoCompra.Add(productocompra1);
            orden1.F_Producto_ProductoCompra.Add(productocompra2);
            distributor1.F_Orden.Add(orden1);
            context.F_Orden.AddObject(orden1);
            context.FDistributors.AddObject(distributor1);
            context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting the value of Id manually?

I believe that identifier in table [F_Producto_ProductoCompra] is `Id INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY`.

So there could be a collision with identifiers.
May be the row with the same Id really exists.

Comment: Lets say that I have already on the database a F_Producto with Id = 2, Nombre = "Aspirine". How would I relate the F_Producto_ProductoCompra to my F_Producto. Since it inherits from Fproducto?